# Spectral theory for $f\mapsto f\circ g$

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, spectral-theory

Consider the Banach space $B = C([0,1] \to \mathbb R)$ of continuous functions from $[0,1] \to \mathbb R$ with the supremum norm. Let $g$ be a continuous function $g:[0,1] \to [0,1]$.

Then one can check easily that 
$$\Phi_g : B\to B,\ \ \ \  \Phi_g  f := f\circ g,$$ is a bounded linear operator with norm $1$.

**Question**: How is the spectrum $\sigma(\Phi_g)$ related to $g$?

There are some simple observations:

- $1 \in \sigma$ as always: It's the eigenvalue with eigenvectors the constant functions.
- If $g$ is not onto, then $0 \in \sigma$ is an eigenvalue (Pick a $f$ with support away from the image of $g$).

There's another observation when $g(0) = 0$, $g$ strictly increasing and $g(1)<1$:

- $[0,1] \subset \sigma$, and all of them are eigenvalues, and with infinite multiplicities when $\lambda \neq 1$. (That result can be found in [Does equation $f(g(x))=a f(x)$ have a solution?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1300780/does-equation-fgx-a-fx-have-a-solution))

What else can we say to the spectrum? Is there a general theory that deal with this operator?

Comment: There is a closely related general theory of composition operators which is very fruitful in the theory of dynamical system. However, the setting there is usually slightly different, in that one has an invariant measure $\mu$ for $g$, and one studies the composition operator $\phi_g$ on the complex $L^2$-space instead of the space of real-valued functions. In this setting it is usually called the Koopman operator, and its spectrum is a conjugacy invariant. If $g$ is invertible, it is a unitary operator on $L^2$.

Answer (score 1):

If $g$ is not one-to-one, then $\Phi_g$ is not onto (since $\Phi_g(f)$ satisfies $\Phi_g(f)(s) = \Phi_g(f)(t)$ whenever $g(s) = g(t)$), so $0 \in \sigma$.

$-1$ is an eigenvalue if $g$ is an involution that is not the identity.  Indeed, take any $s \in [0,1]$ such that $g(s) \ne s$, let $h$ be a continuous function on $[0,1]$ with $h(s) \ne h(g(s))$, and take $f = h - h \circ g$.
You can generalize this slightly: if $g \circ g$ is the identity on some nonempty open set, then $-1$ is an eigenvalue.